# Compilation error of Play framework Templates

Tags: playframework-2.0

hi i am trying to display a form and following a proper tutorial.. 
But i am getting compilation error which is..

missing arguments for method apply in object form; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

My template look like this

```
@main("Example"){
    <h1>SignUp Form</h1>

    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit()) 
    {
        @helper.inputText(signupform("name"))
        @helper.inputText(signupform("password"))
        <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your braces are wrong...

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit()) {
  @helper.inputText(signupform("name"))
  @helper.inputText(signupform("password"))
  <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
}
```

Comment: Yeah the parser is less complex than the real Scala parser. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: I would like to know why this must be on that way? At least, where i can find a good reason for play to work on that way.

Comment: It's an implementation detail - the way Play parses templates using a Scala parser combinator.

Answer (score 0):

signupform is not defined. Use below format in first line to define signupform:

```
@(signupform: Form[_])
```